# Generate a custom date range

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How I can generate a date range, reject some days for example sundays or some holidays and extend the range with a next available day? Obviously I can do something like `(Date.today..Date.today+5.days).reject{|day| day.sunday?}` but this would remove sunday and make my range smaller. How can I solve this? Should I implement a custom Range class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done with a `Range` as @sawa already pointed out.

I think you need to use an array filled with qualified days:

```
def working_days(number)
  [].tap do |days|
    date = Date.today
    while days.size < number
      days << date unless date.sunday? || date.saturday?
      date = date.next
    end
  end
end

working_days(5)
#=> [02 Dec 2015, 03 Dec 2015, 04 Dec 2015, 07 Dec 2015, 08 Dec 2015]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is impossible in general. A range has to be continuous. Unless the date you want to reject is at either end of the original range, that is impossible.

However, by converting the range to an array, you can do a similar thing:

```
(Date.today..Date.today+5.days).to_a.reject(&:sunday?)
```

Comment: so I guess I should be doing something different entirely. :-)